# Looping through pscustomobject dataset and add to a SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a variable, `$CiscoCMDB`, which holds data for 2968 records like this (some fields are all filled, some are not like below):

```
SearchCode: D12345678911
Name1: 1212
Category: Office Phone
AssetTag: 
Status: Stock
SerialNumber: FCH1549BBBB
Model: CISCO IP PHONE 7945G
MacAddress: 
Location: SF
OwnerOrganization: 
OwnerPerson:
```

I also have a SQL DB created, CiscoCMDB, with the same name for the columns that are present for the rows. I would like All records to be written to the SQL table. I've tried to use the `Write-Datatable` cmdlet, but it gave me errors. along with other CMDlets. I figured, if I am using SQL SELECT statements in my code, I should just use SQL INSERTs in my code. Only problem is, I'm not sure how to go about this other than knowing I will need a `foreach` loop to loop through.

Can someone help me on this as I'm getting confused and frustrated. I'm not exactly sure how to go about looping through correctly.

1. Pull data from another SQL DB
2. Organize data furthur (picking the columns I want)
3. Manipulate data to strip `^C` from searchcode (all our search codes are prefaced with C)
4. Manipulate data to strip `^DN` from Name1 field (again all Name1s are prefaced with DN)
5. Fill in my data

```bsh
$CMDBCiscoQuery = @()
    foreach ($row in $table) {
        $hash = [ordered]@{
            'SearchCode' = $row.SearchCode
            'Category' = $row.Category
            'Status' = $row.Status
            'Name1' = $row.Name1
            'SerialNumber' = $row.SerialNumber
            'Model' = $row.Model
            'MacAddress' = $row.MacAddress
            'Location' = $row.Location
            'OwnerOrg' = $row.OwnerOrganization
            'Owner' = $row.OwnerPerson
        }
        $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash
        $CMDBCiscoQuery+= $obj


$CMDBCisco = $CMDBCiscoQuery |
             Select @{n='SearchCode';e={$_.Searchcode -replace "^C"}},
                 @{n='Name1';e={$_.DN -replace "^DN"}}, Category, AssetTag,
                 Status, SerialNumber, Model, MacAddress, Location,
                 OwnerOrganization, OwnerPerson

#Filling CMDB table
Write-Verbose "Filling CMDBCisco Table"

    $ConnectionTimeout = 30
    $ServerInstance = "myserver"
    $Database = "Audits"

    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Connect Timeout={2};Integrated Security = True;" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout
    $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString

    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($conn);

    $conn.Close()
```

Comment: Can you ask your question in a more succinct way? As much as I'd love to read your wall of code, you need to narrow down what you are asking

Comment: Need to ask a little less, here, there's too much to go through. But for #3 / #4 you can just use a SUBSTRING in the query :: substring(col1,3,len(col1)) )

Comment: Hi, sorry! Yes, I'll edit the code.
Owain, I've tried that but there are some values in the dataset that don't preface with ^C(wrong entries that im using the DB to fix).

Comment: I just need to know the steps to correctly loop through $CiscoCMDB to add it to my CiscoCMDB table in SQL. I just need some help getting started on the code to add the correct data to each column in the table.